# Opera Extension: selecting text and page menu

Tags: opera-extension

What is the simplest way to create Opera addon with such functionality: user selects text on the page (eg. **menu**), clicks right button and sees:

[image: context menu]

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [Context Menu extension APIs](http://dev.opera.com/extension-docs/contextMenus.html).